# no description and image title in insert module

Tags: media

I am using [insert](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert) module in drupal 6.

How come I have ***no description and image title*** just like this https://www.drupal.org/files/images/insert-module.png

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution
Enable the insert in content type.
admin/content/node-type/news/fields/field_image2